# Inferring parameter type for a lambda (again!)

Tags: scala, lambda

I am wondering why does this not work (missing parameter type)?

```
 Seq(1,2,3).toSet.map(_ + 1)
```

but this does:

```
 val foo = Seq(1,2,3).toSet
 foo.map(_ + 1)
```

as well as this: (3)

```
  Seq(1,2,3).toSet[Int].map(_ + 1)
```

or this:

```
  Seq(1,2,3).toList.map(_ + 1)
```

What is special about `toSet` that makes it loose the type in the first case, but not in the second?

Comment: The quirks of the Scala compiler will never cease to amaze. Then again, the compiler itself will never cease to amaze either.

Comment: btw, there is no such issue for dotty compiler

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko yeah, dotty is a non-starter for me I am afraid, because of its lack of type projections :(

Comment: one more funny thing about `toSet`: `Seq(1,2,3).toSet()` - returns `boolean`

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko priceless :D

Answer (score 4):

An educated guess:

```
def toSet[B :> A]: Set[B]
```

vs

```
def toList: List[A]
```

For some reason `toSet` is parametric - if you split `toSet` and `map` into two statements, then in first case compiler will have to assume something and assign that type to the `val`, then use `B` guessed to be `A` in `map`.

But with `Seq(1,2,3).toSet.map` it guesses that there is some `B >: Int` which it should then map into... what exactly? You can guess the type of `_ * 2` only if you know the type of `_`.

Long story short that `[B :> A]` seem to be the issue since if we do this:

```
implicit class AsSetOps[F, A](val fa: scala.collection.SeqLike[A, F]) {
  def asSet: Set[A] = fa.toSet[A]
}
Seq(1,2,3).asSet.map(_ * 2)
```

it works.

I can only guess that it was some attempt to make `toSet` covariant which backfired.

Comment: Same pattern applies to `toBuffer` which is also `[B :> A]`. [link](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L305)

Comment: This seems to go back in time quite a lot [link](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/e6efa7b11f44d2e405d02c563b710023b3ef3e8a#diff-f39276c8ffc39c91dbe66a2ae54235b0R252) For `toBuffer` it might be understandable, because it is a mutable (invariant) collection, but for immutable `Set` it might have been added accidentally(?) (no review)... and then it stayed for 8 years. 2.13 still have this problem [link](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/df64638fdaeb987923aa701454b3f169dd96ec9d/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L1266)

Comment: `> You can guess the type of _ * 2 only if you know the type of _ ` Well, yes ... But the same applies to `val foo = bar.toSet`, doesn't it? You can only guess the type of `foo` if you know the type of set. Also, `Set` is _not_ covariant, and, even if it was, I don't see what the return type of `.toSet` _on a different object_ would have to do with it :/

Comment: Difference is in one case compiler is forced to make a decision (resolve `B >: A`), and having no additional knowledge it assumes that `A =:= B` (which I guess is a special case in compiler). If you do 2 constraints at once then you have to consider 2 cases that no special case describes. Basically a corner case of a type system breaking inference, that shouldn't exist in Dotty. I had several other like this over the years.

Comment: If you think about it the whole idea behind Aux pattern is that compiler cannot handle cases like that - needing the type figured out later to figure out type needed earlier.